# Calling TEdit objects based on DB query

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a form with 7 TEdit having name EditPhone1, EditPhone2 and so on.
In the same form I query a DB to get data to fill those TEdits. Of course I cannot know in advance how many results the query will return.
How can I call the various TEdit objects when looping on the rowcount of the query?

Comment: If you have your edit boxes already on a form, make a `TList<TEdit>` generics collection, fill this collection at form creation with all analogous edit boxes and access them like `PhoneEditList[RowIndex].Text`. If I were you, I'd create them dynamically at runtime storing them in the `TObjectList<TEdit>` collection.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FindComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) to "convert" a component name to the component itself:

```
var
  Edit: TEdit;
  I: Integer;
begin
  DataSet.First;
  I := 1;
  while not DataSet.Eof do
  begin
    Edit := TEdit(FindComponent(Format('EditPhone%d', [I])));
    if Edit <> nil then
      Edit.Text := DataSet.FieldValues['PhoneNo'];
    DataSet.Next;
    Inc(I);
  end;
```

Now, this requires to hard-code the `EditPhone%d` string into the source which results in all kinds of maintainability issues. For example: consider renaming the edits.

#### Alternative 1:

To not rely on the component names, you could instead make use of [TLama's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815962/calling-tedit-objects-based-on-db-query#comment17334166_12815962) and add all the edits to a list:

```
uses
  ... , Generics.Collections;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    EditPhone1: TEdit;
    ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FEdits: TList<TEdit>;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FEdits := TList<TEdit>.Create;
  FEdits.AddRange([EditPhone1, EditPhone2, EditPhone3, EditPhone4, EditPhone5,
    EditPhone6, EditPhone7]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FEdits.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  DataSet.First;
  I := 0;
  while (not DataSet.Eof) and (I < FEdits.Count) do
  begin
    FEdits[I].Text := DataSet.FieldValues['PhoneNo'];
    DataSet.Next;
    Inc(I);
  end;
end;
```

This still requires some maintenance in case of adding edits in future.

#### Alternative 2:

You could also loop over all edits in the form to find the ones tagged to be added to the list, instead of adding them each explicitly:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  FEdits := TList<TEdit>.Create;
  for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    if (Components[I] is TEdit) and (TEdit(Components[I]).Tag = 1) then
      FEdits.Add(TEdit(Components[I]));
end;
```

But keeping those tags up to date is another burden.

#### Alternative 3:

I suggest you use a `TDBGrid` which is a data-component. Opening the linked dataset will automatically add all phone numbers to the grid. With some settings, the grid may kind of look like a couple of edits below each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, use Tag property, to find needed component. Set all you TEdit's tag from 1 to 7 (or more), and find component by:

```
Var I: Integer;
    MyEdit : TEdit;

For I = 0 To Self.ComponentCount - 1 Do
 if (Self.Components[I] IS TEdit) AND (Self.Components[I] AS TEdit).Tag = YourTag
   MyEdit = (Self.Components[I] AS TEdit);
```

You can also dynamically create so many TEdits, you need, and assign Tag property on creation, and find it this code later in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `DBCtrlGrid`. You place your controls for one row on it, and it repeats the controls for as many rows as your data set has.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get query result (usually using `.RowCount` property of `TDataset` return)
2. After getting the number of row, do iteration to make `TEdit` and set the text property

Here is sample of code:

```
...
For i:=0 to RowCount do
Begin
 A:=TEdit.Create(self);
 A.Parent:=AForm;
 A.Top:=i*14;
 A.Text:=ADataset.Field(i).AsString;
End;
...
```