# Controlling multiple TEdits as array

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I am trying to programme a Sudoku solver, and I want to control 81 `TEdit` controls as array, but their names are `Edit1`, `Edit2`, `Edit3` instead of `Edit[1]`, `Edit[2]`, etc.

I do not want to type `OnChange` event handlers for all 81 controls separately.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not just use single 9x9 TStringGrid instead ? :-)

Comment: Or if fancy picture is a must, i'd use TButton + TPopupMenu to change digits. A la those smartphones.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do it one by one.
You can select multiple controls on a form using shft-click or ctrl-drag to select them by a rectangle.

So in general:

- Use the Object Inspector to set up the OnChange handler for one Edit
- Optionally rename it to a more general name using the Object Inspector
- Select all other edits on the form
- Select the handler you just created using the Object Inspector.
  It will be assigned to all edits you selected.

Comment: I agree with this approach, form controls can share the same event handlers.

Answer (score 5):

You can create the edits dynamically.

Be sure to set the owner and the parent of the edit boxes.

```
procedure TForm1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  x, y : Integer;
begin
  for y := 1 to 9 do begin
    for x := 1 to 9 do begin
      FEdit[x,y] := TEdit.Create(self);
      FEdit[x,y].Parent := self;
      FEdit[x,y].Left :=   // function based on x
      FEdit[x,y].Top  :=   // function based on y
      FEdit[x,y].Name :=   // function based on x and y
      FEdit[x,y].Width     //  any value you like
      FEdit[x,y].Height    // any value you like
      FEdit[x,y].Tag = 10*y + x;
      FEdit[x,y].OnChange = OnHandleChange;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnHandleChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y : Integer;
begin
  if not Sender is TEdit then Exit;
  y := TEdit(Sender).Tag div 10;
  x := TEdit(Sender).Tag mod 10;
  // Add check if x and y are valid  

 // You now know that FEdit[x,y] is changed and you can handle accordingly.
end;
```

FEdit is a two dimensional array field of the form.

Comment: You missed to show how to commonly handle the `OnChange` event (what was the question I guess) and how to get from that `OnChange` event sender's `FEdit` array coordinates.

Comment: Just a small hint: runtime-made components do not have to get a `Name`. Because whatever name you would give it, you won't use it ever more; there is no variable and the array element is its reference now.

Comment: @NGLN: I find a component name very useful in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var
  myedit: array[1..81] of TEdit;
  i: integer;
...
begin
...
for i := 1 to 81 do begin
  myedit[i] := TEdit.Create(form1);
  with myedit[i] do begin
    width := 50;
    top := 50 + (i * 55);
    left := 50;
    text := 'mytext '+inttostr(i);
    parent := form1;
    // more properties...
    end;
  end;
...
```

You can create whatever you want dynamically, using similar code.

Comment: Wow, that will be a multilayer sudoku :-)

Comment: You missed to show how to commonly handle the `OnChange` event (what was the question I guess) and how to get from that `OnChange` event sender's `myedit` array index. And the `Left` coordinate is still constant in your code, what makes you playing field somehow multilayer :-)

Comment: @TLama, yes I missed onChange, Gamecat did it in his example. About Left coord. that's just an example how to set properties, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks all for help. I mostly liked N2, will try :D

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the use of a common `OnChange` event handler and creating the edits runtime, you could also fill an array with designtime made controls.

As I recently explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846445/757830), you can add designtime made controls to your one- or two-dimensional array: by searching them on name with `FindComponent`, searching them on `Tag` property with a loop, or by manually adding them to the array by typing their 81 variables.

Comment: I managed to write those, but here is another problem, "access violation at adress in module". The code:
procedure TForm1.OnHandleChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  bx,by,x,y,len : Integer;
begin
...
if not (MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text[1] in ['1'..'9']) then
MyEdit[bx,by,x,y].text:='';
....
end;

So, I searched internet 1 hour, it seems to be a common problem.

Comment: @Hasan That's a whole different question (_how to implement a specific solution?_) which is difficult to address in a single comment. Please ask it in a new question.